# How do I redirect to send to other html file in MEAN Stack

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

This Application talks to MongoDB.

In **Index.html** , i have a button:
 ***View***

On click of "**View**" button , a function view() is executed ,which requests the data from mongodb and renders it to same page **Index.html** . 
**view()** have ->

```
  *customerVar.find({}, function(err, customers) {
            if(!err){
                res.send(customers);


            }
            else{
                res.send('could not retrived data');
            }

        });*
```

Here  res.send(customers);  -> Sends it to **index.html**

How do i then redirect it to send to other html file . ?
I want **"view.html"** to display result , when i click button in "**index.html**".

Comment: You mean, you need to get the data available in one component in another one ?

Comment: Yes . The problem was ....  i had to display result in different html file . Rather than in the html page where it has the button .

Comment: why don't you try `EventEmitter`. i think it will do your requirement.

Comment: re.redirect helped for this Jithin .Thanks a lot...... I have now problem with delete operation . Here's the question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437439/delete-operation-angular-js-and-mongodb......                                                                                                    if you can help me .......with this refresh .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render).

Assuming you've properly configured your view engine and have a similar project structure:

```
example
├── app.js
└── views
    ├── index.html
    └── view.html
```

Then your code would be (ES2015 example with error handling omitted):

```
const Customer = require('./path/to/models/Customer')

exports.myHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const customers = await Customer.find({}).exec()
  if (!customers) {
    res.render('index')
    return
  }
  res.render('view', { customers })
}
```

If you had your routes configured, then you would just replace `res.render` with [`res.redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect).